# How do I turn screen logging off?? I did `screen -L` once and now a file called screenlog.0 keeps getting generated

Tags: logging, terminal, gnu-screen, iterm2, iterm

I entered `screen -L` in iTerm2, and now whenever I open a new terminal window, a new file `screenlog.0` gets created and shows up in git, which I don't want (and I don't want to delete it every single time it pops up). I also don't want to add it to `.gitignore`. How do I get rid of it??

I looked at `screen --help` but that only lists the option to turn it ON, not off.

Comment: Try to exit all screen windows.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [unix.se] instead, as it is not programming related. You can find more information about this site in the [help].